# C# How to loop through the source folder or subfolders that match the destination

Tags: c#

I need to overwrite files from a source to a destination directory.
The structure of each folder is different so i'm trying to do it in a generic way. 
The thing is, each folder (source and destination) could have numerous subdirectories or none at all.

The code I currently have is this:

```
//copy and overwrite the files depending on whatever is in the destination
//search through the destination to find the file
foreach (var dstfile in Directory.GetFiles(targetDir))
{
  //search through the source to find the matching file
  foreach (var srcfile  in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
  {
     //cut off the source file from the source path 
     strSrcFile = srcfile.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();
     strDstFile = dstfile.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();

    //if the destination and source files match up, replace the desination with the source
    if (strSrcFile == strDstFile)
    {
      File.Copy(srcfile, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(strSrcFile)), true);
    }
  }
}


//look through the subfolders to see if any files match up 
foreach (var srcFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir))
{
   //search through the source for the files 
   foreach (var srcFile in Directory.GetFiles(srcFolder))
   {
      //search through the destination for the files 
      foreach (var dstFile in Directory.GetFiles(targetDir))
      {
```

As you can see there are a lot of foreach loops, is there a way to streamline this?

Comment: That is way to many  foreach loops for me to fathom.. are you basically just checking if a new directory has a file and if it does then replace it?

Comment: Indeed. However it has to check subdirectories, and if the destination has subdirectories it has to find and overwrite the files in there also.

Comment: so checking each file in a directory against another directory and its sub directories?

Comment: Why not 2 methods: `void overwriteFiles(string srcdir, string targetdir)` and `void walkdirectory(string src, string target)` (called recursively returning when there are no more children)?  Each time you hit a new source directory in the tree call overwriteFiles with current source and its matching target?

Comment: Recursion is the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but this should work (Not 100% efficient), Should give you some pointers at least

```
public void UpdateFiles(string directory, string otherDir)
{
   var dirFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*", 
                        SearchOption.AllDirectories);
   var otherDirFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(otherDir, "*", 
                        SearchOption.AllDirectories);

   foreach (var file in dirFiles)
   {
       string fi = Path.GetFileName(file);
       var newFile = otherDirFiles.Where(x => fi == Path.GetFileName(x));
       foreach(var foundFile in newFile)
          File.Copy(file , foundFile, true);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a hash (dictionary) of the destination directory, then walk the source directory and see if the files already exist.

```
Dictionary<string,string> lut1 = new Dictionary<string,string>();

foreach (var dstfile in Directory.GetFiles(targetDir))
{
   strDstFile = dstfile.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();
   lut1 [strDstFile ] = dstfile;
}

foreach (var srcfile  in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
{
   strSrcFile = srcfile.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();
   string dstfile;
   if (lut1.TryGetValue(strSrcFile,  out dstfile)) {
       File.Copy( srcfile,dstfile,true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did it this way in a console app... tested it to work for main target folder and sub folders, although probably not the most efficient.

Call this:

```
OperateOnSourceFiles(sourceDir, targetDir);
```

Which will check the current files in the source, and then recursively look through all source subdirectories.

```
private static void OperateOnSourceFiles(string source, string targetDir)
{
    //Processes current source folder files
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(source))
    {
        OverWrite(targetDir, file);
    }

    //Recursively processes files in source subfolders
    List<string> subfolders = Directory.GetDirectories(source).ToList();
    foreach (var subfolder in subfolders)
    {
        OperateOnSourceFiles(subfolder, targetDir);
    }
}
```

Then your overwrite function could look something like this:

```
private static void OverWrite(string target, string sourcefile)
{
    //Grab file name
    var strSrcFile = sourcefile.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();

    //Search current target directory FILES, and copy only if same file name
    List<string> targetfiles = Directory.GetFiles(target).Select(file=>file.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last()).ToList();
    if (targetfiles.Contains(strSrcFile))
    {
        File.Copy(sourcefile, Path.Combine(target, Path.GetFileName(strSrcFile)), true);
    }

    //Recursively search current target directory SUBFOLDERS if any
    List<string> subfolders = Directory.GetDirectories(target).ToList();
    foreach (var subfolder in subfolders)
    {
        OverWrite(subfolder, sourcefile);
    }
}
```

Feel free to correct me :)

Note: I realize it's still quite a lot of foreach loops, but at least they aren't nested, and makes life easier when debugging.

Comment: This is slightly right, however I don't want to completely overwrite the subdirectory since the names will probably be different. Just overwrite the contents if they match with either files in the source or files in the source subdirectories

Comment: It doesn't overwrite it the subdir completely, it checks to make sure the source file and target file has the same name and _then_ does a file copy (refer to the Contains(strSrcFile) part). I've also updated the answer to recursively check all source files even in subdirectories of the source

Answer (score 0):

I liked the idea, so I tried this myself. Turned out a bit more complicated then I thought it would. Let's go into a deep dive, okay?

The basic idea is to synchronize directories, so we want references to `DirectoryInfo` instances.

```
var source = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SynchSource");
var target = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SynchTarget");

Synchronize(source, target);
```

`Synchronize` pretty much works in the following manner:

- make sure all files are identical
- make sure all directories are identical
- go through all subdirectories and traverse

My implementation looks like this:

```
void Synchronize(DirectoryInfo sourceDir, DirectoryInfo targetDir)
{
    SynchronizeFiles(sourceDir, targetDir);
    SynchronizeDirectories(sourceDir, targetDir);
    TraverseDirectories(sourceDir, targetDir);
}
```

Note the `.Single()` - we can never assume there is just one person/process working in the directories.

`SynchronizeFiles` does two things:

1. Copy/overwrite all files in the current directory into the target directory.
2. Remove redundant files that no more exist in the source directory

```
void MoveFiles(DirectoryInfo sourceDir, DirectoryInfo targetDir)
{
    foreach (FileInfo sourceFile in sourceDir.GetFiles())
    {
        string targetFilePath = Path.Combine(targetDir.FullName, sourceFile.Name);
        File.Copy(sourceFile.FullName, targetFilePath);
    }
}

void RemoveRedundantFiles(DirectoryInfo sourceDir, DirectoryInfo targetDir)
{
    foreach (var targetFile in targetDir.GetFiles())
    {
        var sourceFilePath = Path.Combine(sourceDir.FullName, targetFile.Name);
        if (!File.Exists(sourceFilePath))
        {
            targetFile.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

We can now assume all files in the current directory are the same, no more and no less. In order to traverse through the subdirectories, we first have to make sure the directory structure is the same. We do it in a similar manner to `SynchronizeFiles`:

1. Create missing directories in the target directory (`CreateMissingDirectories`)
2. Remove redundant directories that no more exist in the source directory (`RemoveRedundantDirectories`)

```
void CreateMissingDirectories(DirectoryInfo sourceDir, DirectoryInfo targetDir)
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo sourceSubDir in sourceDir.GetDirectories())
    {
        string targetSubDirPath = Path.Combine(targetDir.FullName, sourceSubDir.Name);
        if (!Directory.Exists(targetSubDirPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetSubDirPath);
        }
    }
}

void RemoveRedundantDirectories(DirectoryInfo sourceDir, DirectoryInfo targetDir)
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo targetSubDir in targetDir.GetDirectories())
    {
        string sourceSubDirPath = Path.Combine(sourceDir.FullName, targetSubDir.Name);
        if (!Directory.Exists(sourceSubDirPath))
        {
            targetSubDir.Delete(true);
        }
    }
}
```

We are at the state that files and directories in the current level of hierarchy equal. We can now iterate through all subdirectories and call Synchronize:

```
void TraverseDirectories(DirectoryInfo sourceDir, DirectoryInfo targetDir)
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo sourceSubDir in sourceDir.GetDirectories())
    {
        DirectoryInfo targetSubDir = targetDir.GetDirectories(sourceSubDir.Name).Single();
        Synchronize(sourceSubDir, targetSubDir);
    }
}
```

And we are done.

For huge directory hierarchies, a big amount or large files or even concurrent processes working in the directory, there is much room for improvement. There is a lot of work to do for it to be fast (you may want to cache `GetFiles` / `GetDirectories`), skip unnecessary `File.Copy` calls (get a file hash before assuming a copy is needed).

Just as a side note: Other than synchronizing files every now and then, depending on the requirement, you may want to have a look at `FileSystemWatcher`, which can detect all changes recursively in a selected directory.

Comment: One thing about this, the structures of the directories are going to be different. So it has to be extremly generic in order to accodmidate for directories to be different.